# If $d_1$ and $d_ 2$ are two distances in X then are the respective topologies equivalent when $d_ 1$ and $d_2$ are continuous with respect each other?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Let be $d_1$ and $d_2$ two distances in a set $X$ and thus let's we suppose that they are continuous with respect each other, that is $d_1$ is continuous with respect the product topology generated by $d_2$ and vice versa. So if $d_1$ is continuous with respect $d_2$ then for any $\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$ there exists $\delta_\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$ such that
$$
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{1}|d_1(x_1,x_2)-d_1(\xi_1,\xi_2)|<\epsilon\end{equation}
$$
for any $(x_1,x_2)\in B_{d_2}(\xi_1,\delta_\epsilon)\times B_{d_2}(\xi_2,\delta_\epsilon)$ where $\xi_1,\xi_2\in X$ are fixed: so putting
$$
x_0:=\xi_1,\xi_2
$$
for any fixed $x_0\in X$ and thus let's we observe that the inequality $\eqref{1}$ implies that
$$
d_1(x,x_0)<\epsilon
$$
for any $x\in B_{d_2}(x_0,\delta_\epsilon)$, that is
$$
B_{d_2}(x_0,\delta_\epsilon)\subseteq B_{d_1}(x_0,\epsilon)
$$
so that actually the inclusion
$$
\begin{equation}\tag{2}\label{2}\mathcal T_{d_1}\subseteq\mathcal T_{d_2}\end{equation}
$$
holds.

So we proved that if $d_1$ is continuous with respect $d_2$ then $\mathcal T_{d_1}$ is smallest than $\mathcal T_{d_2}$. Analogously switching the subscript $1$ with $2$ it is possible to prove the reverse of $\eqref{2}$.

So unfortunately I did not find this result anywhere but I think that it can be very useful so that I thought to put a specific question where I ask to test my proof if the result holds or to show a counterexample if this it not. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: @Surb I edit the question: precisely I want mead that if $d_1$ is continuous with respect the product topology generated by $d_2$ then the inclusion $(2)$ holds. Forgive the mistake.

Comment: @Surb Sorry, I did not understand your last comment: did you explain better, please? did you read my last comment?

Comment: @Surb $d_1$ is a function $X^2\to\Bbb R$, is this function continuous when $X$ has the topology induced by $d_2$ and $X^2$ has the product topology? That's what the asker means

Comment: @Surb Sorry, I repeat myself. I want mead that if $d_1$ is continuous with respect the 
 product topology generated by $d_2$ then the inclusion $(2)$ holds. Is this uncorrect?

Comment: I think Alessandro Codenotti understood what I wanted mean.

Comment: @Surb You are right about $If(d_1)\in\mathbb R,$ but we can definitely define continuity of $d_1$ relative to $d_2.$ Namely, $d_2$ defines a topology on $X,$ and thus we get a product topology on $X\times X.$ And then we can ask if $d_1:X\times X\to \mathbb R$ is continuous.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You say right. So is the result true? what can you say about my proof?

Comment: Where you say "$x_0 ;= \xi_1, \xi_2$". it looks like you actually mean "setting $x_2 = \xi_1 = \xi_2 := x_0$", and the result holds for any $x \in B_{d_2}(x_0, \delta_\epsilon)$, not $\epsilon$ itself, so the following line becomes $B_{d_2}(x_0, \delta_\epsilon) \subseteq B_{d_1}(x_0, \epsilon)$. However, that does not change the final inclusion of topologies, which still follows. With these minor corrections, I think the argument is fine.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Oh right! thanks really for the check!

Comment: The result is true and your work is good. The other comments are mainly about clarifying what it means for a metric to be continuous with respect to another.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Perfect, thanks very much for your check. Moreover I think that also the reverse result holds, right?

Comment: Yes,  The converse (reverse) also holds.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Okay, perfect: thanks very much for your assistance!!! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in the question I proved that if $d_1$ and $d_2$ are two distance on a set $X$ such that $d_1$ is continuous when $X\times X$ is equipped with the topology generated by $d_2$ then the inclusion
$$
\begin{equation}\tag{i}\label{i}\mathcal T_{d_1}\subseteq\mathcal T_{d_2}\end{equation}
$$
holds: so the result is true. However it is also true the reverse, that is if the inclusion $\eqref{i}$ holds then an analogous inclusion between the product topologies on $X\times X$ holds so that any function in $X\times X$ which is continuous with respect the product topology of $d_1$ is continuous with respect the product topology of $d_2$ so that $d_1$ is continuous with respect this last topology because any distance is continuous with respect own product topology.